# Wordpress Woocommerce Orders by Author

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a author based woocommerce shop.. What I try to do is show posts only by the author, and orders made by customers link to the product author..

This is what I got so far:

```
function show_author_posts_only($query) {
global $user_level, $woocommerce, $product;

if($query->is_admin && $user_level < 5) {
    global $user_ID;

    $query->set('post_author',  get_post_field( 'post_author', $product_id ));
    $query->set('author',  $user_ID);
    unset($user_ID);
}
unset($user_level);

return $query; 
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'show_author_posts_only');
```

To bad I am stuck on the orders part.. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 we need to now add this to our sorting dropdown and our WooCommerce settings.

 <?php 
 function sv_custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['alphabetical'] = 'Sort by sell: alphabetical';
    return $sortby;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'sv_custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'sv_custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );


//Add Alphabetical sorting option to shop page / WC Product Settings
function sv_alphabetical_woocommerce_shop_ordering( $sort_args ) {
  $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );

    if ( 'alphabetical' == $orderby_value ) {
        $sort_args['orderby'] = 'author';
        $sort_args['order'] = 'asc';
        $sort_args['meta_key'] = '';
    }

    return $sort_args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'sv_alphabetical_woocommerce_shop_ordering' );
?>
```